# Как проверить видимость дочернего окна на winapi?

Tags: winapi, c++

Как проверить видимость дочернего окна на winapi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. лайт-версия - `IsWindowVisible`
2. `Visible`, значит берем его координаты (`GetWindowRect`) и координаты клиентской области родительского окна (`GetClientRect`); если `IntersectRect` для этих Rect'ов вернет `TRUE` - окно видимо, иначе - нет.

для Rect'а дочернего окна перед вызовом `IntersectRect` нужно еще сделать преобразование: `MapWindowPoints( HWND_DESKTOP, hwndParent, ... )`.

Кодом:

```
bool IsChildWindowVisible( HWND hwnd ){
    RECT rc, rw;
    HWND hwndParent;
    //
    if( !::IsWindowVisible( hwnd ) ){
        return false;
    }
    ::GetWindowRect( hwnd, &rw );
    hwndParent = ::GetParent( hwnd );
    ::GetClientRect( hwndParent, &rc );
    ::MapWindowPoints( HWND_DESKTOP, hwndParent, (POINT*)&rw, 2 );
    return ::IntersectRect( &rw, &rw, &rc ) ? true : false;
}
```

---

> как определить, отображается ли окно на экране или спрятано за другими окнами?

[[@mikelsv](/users/2575/mikelsv)](/users/2575/mikelsv), здесь немного сложнее, т.к. мы уже должны отталкиваться не от прямоугольной области, а от региона исходного дочернего окна. Решение сводится к проходу "братских" окон, расположенных выше в `Z-порядке`, с помощью `GetNextWindow( hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV )` и вырезанием из прямоугольного регона исходного окна (`CreateRectRgn`) всех прямоугольников этих "братских" окон (`SetRectRgn`, `CombineRgn`). Проход братских окон не обязательно осуществлять до конца. Если `CombineRgn` на какой-то итерации вернет `NULLREGION`, значит окно уже не видимо. Собственно, это и есть признак результата функции.

Кодом:

```
bool IsSiblingWindowVisible( HWND hwnd ){
    RECT rw;
    HWND hwndSibling;
    HRGN hrgnTop, hrgnSibling;
    bool Result;
    //
    if( !::IsWindowVisible( hwnd ) ){
        return false;
    }
    ::GetWindowRect( hwnd, &rw );
    if( ::IsRectEmpty( &rw ) ){
        return false;
    }
    hrgnTop     = ::CreateRectRgn( rw.left, rw.top, rw.right, rw.bottom );
    hrgnSibling = ::CreateRectRgn( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    hwndSibling = ::GetNextWindow( hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV );
    for( Result = true ; hwndSibling ; ){
        ::GetWindowRect( hwndSibling, &rw );
        if( !::IsRectEmpty( &rw ) ){
            ::SetRectRgn( hrgnSibling, rw.left, rw.top, rw.right, rw.bottom );
            if(NULLREGION == ::CombineRgn( hrgnTop, hrgnTop, hrgnSibling, RGN_DIFF )){
                Result  = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        hwndSibling = ::GetNextWindow( hwndSibling, GW_HWNDPREV );
    }
    ::DeleteObject( hrgnSibling );
    ::DeleteObject( hrgnTop );
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Не подскажете, как определить, отображается ли окно на экране или спрятано за другими окнами? попробовал IsChildWindowVisible(), не работает.

Comment: >Не подскажете, как определить, отображается ли окно на экране или спрятано за другими окнами?

расширил ответ