# vba макросы Excel 2016 : Bag - Windows().Activate и Woorkbooks().Activate периодически не выполняются

Tags: winapi, excel, vba, gdi

Макросы написанные в VBA Excel 2010 (в файле `nameFile`) с использованием `Application.Windows(nameFile).Activate` периодически перестают работать в Excel 2016. Проблема появилась в декабре прошлого года после принудительно перехода нашей компании с Office 2010 на Office2016.

Две книги: одна запускает макрос, а вторая книга содержит макрос - находятся в одном инстансе (сервере автоматизации) Excel. Фокус в окно с книгой `nameFile` передается, но видимой на экране (только уже без фокуса, c изменением цвета имени файла) остается окно с книгой, из которой макрос запускается. Вместе с макросом, также перестает работать функция Excel по упорядочению окон как в максимизированном так и в минимизированном режиме. Т.е отрисовка окна с книгой `nameFile` (которая содержит макросы) не происходит ни средствами VBA, ни встроенными средствами самого Excel, как будто окно `nameFile` скрыто, хотя это не так. Команда из проекта VBA:

`Application.Windows(nP5).Activate`

1. Замена на аналог `Application.Workbooks(nameFile).Activate` не работает.
2. Установка перед и после `Application.Windows(nameFile).Activate` сэндвича из команд `Application.EnableEvents = false` и `Application.EnableEvents = true` ничего не даёт см.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738609/with-excel-2016-vba-will-not-activate-an-alternate-worksheet-when-the-macro-is
3. Установка перед и после `Application.Windows(nameFile).Activate` сэндвича из команд `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` и `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` ничего не даёт.
4. Запуск перед активизацией книги команды `DoEvents`  бесполезен.
5. Команда `Application.ThisWorkbook.Activate` (выполняемый макрос находится в файле  `nameFile`) также нечего не дает.
6. `Caption` в заголовках окон не меняется.
7. При отладке видно, что `Application.ActiveWorkbook`, после выполнения указанных в заголовке команд, не меняется - т.е. как указывал на первую книгу, так и указывает.

NB: после выполнения указанной выше команды 1) Связанное с новой книгой окно получает фокус но GDI это окно не отображает а новая книга в сервере Excel не становится активной. 2) Связанное со старой книгой окно, как и положено, теряет фокус но старая книга почему-то остается активной Application.ActiveWorkbook ?

Проблема временно решается (до следующей перегрузки Win10) после однократного  - ручного переключения фокуса с рабочей книги на новую `nameFile`(активизация окна без действий в нем) и обратно. При этом никаких изменений в макросах я не делаю.

Office2016(16.0.4954.1000) MSO (16.0.4939.1000) 32 Bit и Windows10 (версия 1809), имеют корпоративные лицензии VL и LTSC cоответственно и автоматически обновляются (25.02.2020 установлено последнее обновление KB4484256 вручную). Макросов много, и данная ошибка может возникнуть в любом из них. Очевидно что это bag MS. Есть ли решение проблемы устойчивой работы без перехода на другой Office (ИТ-ки уверяют, что Office2019 мне поможет, но я не уверен)?  Возможно проблема решится переустановкой MS Excel 2016 для VL в более поздних обновлениях MS?

При очередном "подвисании" команды активизации для книги `nameFile` было выявлено, что, одноименные, главное окно класса XLMAIN и окно класса EXCEL7 имеют очень странные видимые размеры `Client Rect` : (0,0)-(0,0), 0x0? Параметр `Rectangle`  для первого окна: (-32000,-32000)-(-31840,31972), 160x28 а для второго окна: (-32000,-31666)-(-32000,31666), 0x0.   При запуске макроса текущее окно теряет фокус (изменяется цвет имени файла). Очевидно фокус переходит на книгу `nameFile`  , но его отображения из-за нулевых размеров не происходит.

После однократного "танца с бубном" с переключением фокуса , указанные выше параметры нормализуются и составляют для первого окна:  `Client Rect`  = (8,7)-(1928,1087), 1920x1080 а  `Rectangle`  = (-8,-8)-(1928,1088), 1936x1096(Maximized), для второго окна:  `Client Rect`  = (0,0)-(1920,724), 1920x724 а  `Rectangle`  = (0,333)-(1920,1057), 1920x724(Maximized)

При очередном зависании окно XLMAIN имело по  прежнему нулевой размер клиентской области, в то время как окно EXCEL7 имело другой  `Client Rect` : (0,0)-(1920,824), 1920x824. Теперь параметр  `Rectangle`  для первого окна остался равным: (-32000,-32000)-(-31840,31972), 160x28 а для второго окна изменился на: (-32000,-31766)-(-30080,-30942), 1920x824.

Периодически из этого же файла я запускаю свою форму (для проведения расчетов) и устанавливаю ей модальность с помощью WinAPI  `SetWindowPos Application.hwnd, -1, rX, rY , 0, 0, 1 Or 2` . Может остается какой-нибудь "мусор" в системе и это как-то между собой связано?

С инстансом Excel 2016 не сразу разобрался. Если в MS Office 2010 все книги  (класс EXCEL7) открываемые из одного макроса находились в одном сервере автоматизации Excel (класс XLMAIN, он же = инстанс) то в MS Office 2016, все книги открываемые из одного макроса по факту находятся в  одном сервере, но в дереве окон выглядят так как будто находятся в разных серверах, поскольку включены в иерархию окон на самый верхний уровень, как и отладчик VBA Excel (именно так показывает MS Spy++).
Данную особенность (вероятно всего не документированную) мне пришлось учитывать в скриптах автокликера Pilot при переходе с MS Excel 2010 на MS Excel 2016. Также замечено, что при сохранении книг выгруженных из SAP формата  `*.xls`  с переименованием в формат  `*.xlsx` , новая  книга создается в новом инстансе Excel, при этом  старая книга сохраняется и именно она остается активной и в фокусе. Чтобы скопировать данные из новой книги в буфер обмена, приходится  Pilot-ом принудительно устанавливать на него фокус. Необычное поведение Excel 2016, не входит в рамки моего первичного вопроса и не требует уточнения, могу только предположить, что при больших циклах обработки у Excel возможны проблемы с реентерабельностью.

Поскольку ошибки Office 2016 без помощи MS не исправить, хочется понять как свойствами объектов VBA или WinAPI "отлавливать" ситуации с некорректными размерами окон классов XLMAIN, EXCEL7 и как размеры принудительно скорректировать, чтобы стало возможным отобразить эту книгу средствами GUI

Проблема отображения окна находящегося в фокусе, но имеющего нулевые клиентские размеры решилась добавлением одной команды:  `Application.WindowState = xlMaximized`

Остается последний вопрос: как "отловить"  ситуацию с некорректными клиентскими размерами окон классов XLMAIN, EXCEL7 , чтобы не выполнять лишний раз команду:

`Application.WindowState = xlMaximized` ?

Comment: 1) А у Window так, чисто случайно, Caption не меняется? 2) Window.Activate всего лишь меняет z-order окон, но не обеспечивает отрисовки - проверяйте ScreenUpdating и попробуйте явный DoEvents. Ну и в порядке бреда - а в это время у вас единственный инстанс Excel в системе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что so - не форум, если у вас есть дополнение к вопросу - его НЕ НАДО писать в поле ОТВЕТ, поле ответ предназначено для публикации решений вопроса, а не уточнений.

Comment: А пробовал отключать ScreenUpdating до переключения и включать после или включать/выключать перед операциями?

Answer (score 0):

1. Проблема отображения окна находящегося в фокусе, но имеющего нулевые клиентские размеры решилась добавлением одной команды:

> Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

2. Выявить ситуацию с некорректными клиентскими размерами окон классов XLMAIN, EXCEL7 поможет использование

> WinAPI: GetWindowRect, GetClientRect, IntersectRect и MapWindowPoints

:
[Как проверить видимость дочернего окна на winapi?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259271/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-winapi/259320#259320)